# How can htaccess replace www for the current directory name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**First**

Is it possible to stablish a rewrite rule so that when I type in the url bar
 **blog.mywebsite.com/file**
 it redirects to
 **www.mywebsite.com/blog/file.php?**
The same if i wanted to go to the store directory of the site. Could I have a rule to redirect
 **store.mywebsite.com/file**
 to
 **www.mywebsite.com/store/file.php?**

**Second**
Provided first part is ok, how could I do it to redirect this
**blog.mywebsite.com/file/this-is-my-article**
 to
 **www.mywebsite.com/blog/file.php?url=this-is-my-article**

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[^.]+\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1/file.php? [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[^.]+\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /%1/file.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,R=302]
```